# que métodos hay para extraer lo que escribió el usuario carácter por carácter?

Tags: python

Soy principiante en Python, trato de extraer de un input lo que escribí pero necesito extraerlo por partes, un método que pueda extraer un numero de caracteres que yo le diga, he usado esto:

```py
código = input()
extraer_subcadena1 = código[0:1]
```

Sin embargo quiero que cada que pase por el bucle while cambie a un numero de caracteres distinto y no puedo hacerlo porque no se como hacer un algoritmo que pueda cambiar esto `[0:1]` a por ejemplo esto `[1:2]` cada que pase por el bucle while

Comment: `for c in codigo: print(c)` ?

Comment: también puedes implementar un generador

Comment: Veo que estas aprendiendo, la verdad no es necesario complicarse para extraer los caracteres. Lo normal es indexar la lista dentro de un `ciclo-for`, indexar es ponerle el número dentro de corchetes `codigo[0]`. Algo así como el comentario de @christian. Hay varias formas, depende el caso. si es por fuera de un `loop` prefiero hacerlo así: `s1,s2,s3,s4,*_=codigo`

Answer (score 0):

para este caso te recomiendo leer acerca del bucle for https://j2logo.com/bucle-for-en-python/

para este algoritmo lo que quieres es que se imprima un indice de la cadena comenzando desde el 0 y que termine en la ultima letra.

Primero: para saber cuando mide una cadena en python se usa el metodo len en una cadena de texto. por ejemplo tengo la variable cadena y quiero saber cuantos caracteres mide entoces, haciendo uso del metodo tengo:

```
cadena = "Hola Mundo"
print(len(cadena)) ##  El resultado es 10
```

Una vez sabiendo cuanto mide la cadena se hace uso del ciclo `for` por lo que lo uso de esta manera
(Ojo, como es un input del usuario y no sabemos cuanto mide se le asigna el valor del metodo len a una variable)

```
codigo = input('Introduce un texto: ')
longitud = len(codigo)

for letras in range(longitud): #Esta parte se puede simplificar pero haciendolo de este modo podras ver mejor como funciona 
    print(codigo[letras:letras+1])
```

y como salida te va a dar:

```
H
o
l
a

M
u
n
d
o
```

Comment: creo que si me sirve, solo no entendí de donde sacaste la variable "letras", ósea en el código que valor tiene esa variable? es lo que no entendí

Comment: @Derek `letras` es una variable de control, esa variable tomará el valor de `0` hasta la longitud de la palabra -1